# Monitor a process in java

Tags: java, unix, solaris, process-monitoring

I have java process which uses process builder and calls a perl script.
The perl script internally calls a binary in background and i have its process id in that perl script.Now i can return this process id back to java.

So now I have the process id in java.
I just want to monitor that process in java whether its running or whether its not running.
How can i do this monitoring inside java.
Probably i need java threads but i am a bit new to java.So could anybody please suggest some directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to check the `/proc` [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)

If process 1234 exists, there's a corresponding file entry `/proc/1234`.

Answer (score 0):

Java monitors only the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) created with [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class or [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a native command like `ps aux | grep <pid>` and get the output of that command from within java using a class like `ProcessBuilder`. Interpreting the output will tell you if the process is still running.

Comment: This is not Java implementation.